# In an XML document with prolog, how can I get the children of the root node with their attributes?

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, txmldocument

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyApp_Favorites version="1.0">
  <Favorite Path="D:\MyTextA.txt" Page="2"/>
  <Favorite Path="D:\MyTextB.txt" Page="33"/>
  <Favorite Path="D:\MyTextC.txt" Page="1"/>
</MyApp_Favorites>
```

Now I try to start to read the children of **MyApp_Favorites** and their respective attributes by starting to read the root node (and then I would try to read the children of the root node):

```
procedure TFormMain.LoadFavorites;
var
  XMLDoc: TXMLDocument;
  ThisRootNode, ThisFavNode: IXMLNode;
begin
  XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  XMLDoc.LoadFromFile('R:\test.xml');
  XMLDoc.Active := True;
  ThisRootNode := XMLDoc.ChildNodes.First;
  CodeSite.Send('ThisRootNode.Text', ThisRootNode.Text);
```

However, `ThisRootNode.Text` gives me back:

> version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"

But doesn't the XML specification say that the XML Prolog is not part of the XML document content? So why do I get the XML Prolog as part of the XML document? And how can I get the root node **MyApp_Favorites** and then its **Favorite** child nodes with their attributes?

Comment: You need to access `XMLDoc.DocumentElement`, not `XMLDoc`.

Comment: But with `XMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First` I get an `Invalid pointer operation` error.

Comment: Very strange: When I write `XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);` I get the `invalid pointer operation` error. But when I write `XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(Self);` then there is no error. Why?

Comment: OK, when I use `Self` as the owner of the `TXMLDocument` object instance then everything works as expected and the problem is solved :) I assume that I have to free the `TXMLDocument` object or is automatically freed by the owning form when the form is destroyed?

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument). When you create `TXMLDocument` with a `nil` Owner, it acts as a reference counted interface object, so you need to assign it to an `IXMLDocument` interface variable, not a `TXMLDocument` variable, to maintain the reference counting correctly. In which case, you should use [`LoadXMLDocument()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.LoadXMLDocument) instead of `LoadFromFile()` directly.

Comment: Here we are again at malicious downvoting of my legitimate and well-formulated questions (was +1 before) by some specific people without any explanations!